# Electron App: Turn off On-Screen Keyboard Windows 10 Tablet

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-10, tablet, electron

I've written an electron application and implemented my own input widgets to be used with my application - optimized for mobile touch input.
Whether this is a good idea in general or not should be not part of this discussion.

My problem now is that when i install my application on a Windows 10 Tablet the OS will open the on-screen keyboard whenever i focus an input-field.

Of course the on-screen keyboard can be toggled off in windows itself - unfortunately it doesn't seem to work as expected...
If i turn off the keyboard it will not show anymore anywhere - windows explorer, browser - nowhere. It works as intended.
But the electron app STILL opens it even if i STOPPED the corresponding windows service.

So my conclusion is that electron itself opens the keyboard and ignores whatever the system tells it about it. I didn't find any documentation or API to turn this feature off though.

Does anyone have any idea how i can achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance,

Patrick

Comment: How is the user to type into an input field without a keyboard?

Comment: as said i have implemented my own input widgets. part of it is a custom onscreen keyboard. it is important that the user will have to use this widget and no other (for example the one from the OS)
there are reasons for this, but explaining them would go beyond the purpose of this thread.

Comment: In that case why use an input field at all then? Why not just have a read-only text box and use those widgets to update the text in that text box? One other thing you can do is to disable all touch events for the whole app. I can provide the answer how to do that if you want. You could also listen to the touch events on this one input box and `preventDefault()` on them so they don't bubble up

Comment: hey @justin.m.chase - thank you for your answer. there are several reasons why i use native input fields, but again, it would be too complicated to explain all my reasoning. i use angularjs as a framework and extended input fields in order to make use of plenty of pre-implemented features on them. unfortunately i can not disable any events or anything because the application will have to run on different devices and behave in the same way. the only option is to prevent the OS from doing what it shouldn't do in the first place anyhow - namely pop up the keyboard which has been toggled off

Comment: Then I think you have to cover up the UI elements you don't want to get focus and then handle the touch events yourself.

Comment: that's not possible since there is too much magic happening in the background which is correlated with the fact that those are native input elements. i really need a solution to my question and not just some workarounds ;) re-writing all that stuff in a work-around manner would take weeks which are not paid by the customer. that is not possible.

Comment: @PatrickKelleter Did you ever come up with a solution? I'm running into the same issue. I've added "onfocus='blur()'" to the form element, and the stops the keyboard from appearing, but it also disables the curser which makes it hard for users to see what they are doing...

Comment: @JasonSmall you can check my self-answer for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately i found out by myself now, that this is not possible currently.
After investigating some electron and chromium source code i managed to find the place the keyboard is opened, which happens to be in the chromium implementation of textfields.
In order to support such a feature in electron there will first have to be an option in chromium to fully disable the onscreen keyboard, which there is not by now, unfortunately.
If that feature would be implemented electron could implement this option itself and pass it through to chromium.
I've started a discussion about it on github, hopefully enough people will upvote the issue and chromium will extend its code accordingly.

For those who desperately need a workaround:
The only thing i was able to come up with after checking the sourcecode is to put an "readonly" on my input fields, since chromium will not open the keyboard on readonly fields.
The downside, of course, is that you will not be able to use the keyboard anymore for these fields, plus, the blinking cursor will not show up, so it feels a big odd to work with it.

Comment: Hello! I can't seem to find any other information about this, being years later I find it odd to be honnest. Any chance you found another solution or a workaround for electron?

My use case is that I have a QR Code reader and I want to "paste" the content in a hidden input, but without the keyboard showing up.

I run on Windows 10 (haven't tried disabling the virtual keyboard from windows settings yet...)